# BackgroundWorker ReportProgress no loop just long database operation

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have .NET 4.5 Windows Forms application where one of the methods takes a while to complete (it's a BulkCopy function which loads a considerable amount of data and pushes into SQL).

I would like to use a BackgroundWorker and ReportProgress so the user will know that there is something going on. I made a few applications that use this but all of them are in some kind of a loop when the BackgroundWorker is doing work and I can easily ReportProgress inside each loop step.

Here I have a problem because there is no loop, code steps would be:

1. worker start async
2. get data from DB2 into a datatable (this takes the most time)
3. SqlBulkCopy datatable into SQL table

I would need to start reporting progress (albeit a fake progress percentage, a simple spinning progress bar would suffice) between step 1. and 2. and end reporting progress after step 3.

Anyone had a similar problem/solution, I guess I could just display a GIF image and hide it after work is done, but I think this won't work as the form freezes (Not responding message).

Comment: @huMpty duMpty: it's not a specific coding problem, I was looking for a solution, for more visibility I tagged both c# and vb.net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Marquee style of the ProgressBar to show indeterminate length of an active process:

```
BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;
bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
  // long work
}

void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
  progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
  progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
}
```

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for, simple and fast, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to display an animated GIF image on the form.  The form will not freeze the animation as long as the work is being done properly in a background thread.  If the form is still freezing, that means it's not actually doing the work on the background thread like you think it is.  Alternatively, you could use a timer to periodically update another kind of control such as a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Have you think about using a Timer / Thread or a custom event.
You can update the user notification message within the timer event handler

```
 try  {
        // Start a Timer                     
       // Write from the source to the destination.
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the SqlDataReader. The SqlBulkCopy 
                // object is automatically closed at the end 
                // of the using block.
                reader.Close();
               // Stop the Timer
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution to report more accurate progress percentage:

```
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    void Start()
    {
        dt.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(dt_RowChanged);
        progressBar1.Maximum = dtRowsCount;
        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void dt_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        bgWorker.ReportProgress(1);
    }

    void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Your work
    }

    void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value += e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting solution, there would be a slight delay when first calling SELECT COUNT(*) to get dtRowsCount but this shouldn't be a big problem.